# man -k returns no results

Tags: man, apropos

I was following a tutorial and thought why not...let me brush up on the `man` command...and low and behold I learned a few things after years working with different flavours of Unix.

On my RHEL7 *however*, trying out the new trick to be able to look-up keywords failed!

It sounds crazy, but having tried it under *root* and under my own username the following shows no results...now *man* has dozens of entries with *time* as a keyword...any help would be appreciated, as I think the keyword facility is very useful for and admin.

```
$ man -k time
time: nothing appropriate.
```

Comment: I did do a search before posting this newbie type question. The question listed at the top of this page as the duplicate, is similar but not what I have actually posed. The duplicate above listed as the answer returns values to the user; additionally it is [apropos] specific and although yes...they are equivalent, again, I think my question, from a newbie perspective is very helpful. Finally, and this might be overkill, but the  man -k command, should at least output a hint regarding the building of the search key command to give a newbie a clue. For all those Linux gurus out there, sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Need to create the database.  `mandb -c` should do it.  Example below.

```
# man -k foo
foo: nothing appropriate.
# mandb -c
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
...
Checking for stray cats under /var/cache/man/local...
89 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
7168 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
# man -k foo
ip-fou (8)           - Foo-over-UDP receive port configuration
#
```

Manual page for `mandb` can be found [here, see "-c" option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mandb.8.html).