# man -k / apropos "nothing appropriate." for "compilation" word from man objdump description

Tags: man, apropos

I've read couple of posts ([man -k returns no results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323007/man-k-returns-no-results)) and first run `mandb` (nothing was updated), then `mandb -c` (`7438 manual pages were added.`), still

`$ apropos compilation
compilation: nothing appropriate.`

But

```
$ MANWIDTH=120 man objdump | grep -B 5 compilation  
DESCRIPTION
       objdump displays information about one or more object files.  The options control what particular information
       to display.  This information is mostly useful to programmers who are working on the compilation tools, as
```

clealy shows `compilation` is within `DESCRIPTION` part of man page.

```
$ man apropos  
Each manual page has a short description available within it.  apropos searches the descriptions for instances of keyword.
```

Why couldn't `apropos` find it?

*System: Linux Mint 19.*

Answer (score 2):

When `man apropos` refers to “a short description”, it’s not referring to the “DESCRIPTION” section of the manpage, but to the short description which follows the command name in the “NAME” section. In `objdump`’s case, that’s

> **NAME**
>
> `objdump` - display information from object files.

*i.e.* the short description is “display information from object files”.

Indeed,

```
apropos "object files"
```

finds `objdump`.

Comment: looks correct, that is much less info searched than I realized before.