# man -k . is not working in gnu/linux

Tags: command-line, man, gnu, coreutils

I am using `manjaro` and when i try command `man -k .` or `apropos .` or `man -k . -s 2` to see all man pages it's giving me error like

`.: nothing appropriate.`

is it `man` different because i gnu coreutils ? what should i do for print all man pages then ?

is there is alternative way to do this then let me know.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323007/216907

Comment: @thanasisp I tried mandb -c as well but also got error in " man -k . "

Comment: Have you tried using the root account? (it's for system files for all users) If yes, and still not working, update your question with that, to queue for re-opening.

Comment: @thanasisp hey thanks it's working after sudo now .